# How can we define any function in XSD or any logic is that possible? Need possibilities in XSD for validation of XML file

Tags: xml, xsd

## Sample XSD file for reference

I want to know whether can we define any function or any encryption/decryption logic in xsd or list of what special features xsd can support?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
<xs:element name="Customer">
<xs:complexType>
<xs:sequence>
<xs:element name="name" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" />
<xs:element name="address" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" />
</xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

Answer (score 0):

No, this is not possible. XML schema is declarative and doesn't provide a facility to specify imperative logic or what most people would recognise as "code". The set of features provided by XML schema is best summarised by [its specification](https://www.w3.org/TR/xmlschema11-1/)

Answer (score 0):

You haven't stated your actual requirement (what is the validation rule you want to impose?). XSD 1.1 allows you to define assertions using XPath, including the full XPath function library; and a particular implementation of XSD 1.1 may allow those XPath expressions to call out to extensions written in a procedural language like Java.

So if you're using pure XSD 1.0 then the answer is no, but if you're prepared to adopt a solution that only works with Saxon (say), then the answer becomes yes.

Comment: I am using XSD 1.1. please post any example XSD for this ?

Comment: In Saxon you could do for example `<xs:assert test="Q{java:com.admfactory.cards.Cards}luhnCheck($value)"/>` to check that a value conforms to the Luhn checksum algorithm as implemented here: https://www.admfactory.com/luhn-algorithm-implementation-in-java/

Comment: You could also define a simpleType `LuhnString` that is derived by restriction from xs:string with the constraining facet `<xs:assertion test=" (as above) "/>` and then declare the type of relevant elements/attributes as `type="LuhnString"`.